# Why Swift cannot remove spaces when compiling code?

Tags: swift

Quite new to Swift, compared to Java and C++...I'm just wondering why Swift doesn't remove spaces when compiling code as following:

```
if x!=10 {...} //I have to add space before and after != to get rid of issue.
```

Increment like increment++ as well can not be act as increment in For syntax if I don't put a space between increment++ and { of loop block.

As in Java or C++, space and Tab do not make sense in terms of compiling. Is Swift just like Python in the way of consider space or tab as part of code?

Comment: For the compiler, `x!` could mean an unwrapped optional. Without a space between `x` and `!=`, the syntax is ambiguous, that's all. Always write your spaces properly and you won't have problems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The exclamation mark is not only used as `not` for example. It is also used to unwrap an optional variable.

There is more syntactic difference to other languages.

Answer (score 5):

Swift does not consider spaces as important, however it uses them when separating characters into lexemes.

Consider the following:

```
a != 1
a! =1
a!= 1
a!=1
```

The first one can be compiled because the lexical analysis correctly recognizes lexems `a`, `!=` and `1`, `!=` being an infix operator.

In the second one, the lexical analysis recognizes lexem `a` with a postfix operator `!` and a `1` with a prefix operator `=`.

The third one is lexem `a` with a postfix operator `!=` and lexem `1`.

The last one is ambiguous because it can be either `a! = 1` or `a != 1`. The compiler decided probably based on operator priority to use `a! = 1`.

Spaces are ignored but they still have a meaning when distinguishing between ambiguous cases. The same is actually valid in many languages. The fact that you can define your own operators limits a bit your coding style.

To compare, try `a+++b` in Java or C++. Will it be `a++ + b` or `a + ++b`?

Comment: Thanks Sulthan...I still have another question in my post which may be asked by others before...Why can't I put increment like i++ in For without space as I do in Java and C++...

Comment: @AlanHoo Swift has removed the operator in Swift 3. Use `i += 1` instead. The C-style `for` loop has been removed too by the way.